# How to change eav_attribute table's note column's datatype varchar to mediumtext using declarative schema?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.1, declarative-schema

I have follow this documnet https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html but not get success

**module.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <!--
        /**
         * Copyright © Krish TechnoLabs, All rights reserved.
         */
        -->
        <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
            <module name="Ktpl_Test1" setup_version="1.0.0">
                <sequence>
                    <module name="Magento_Eav"/>
                </sequence>
            </module>
        </config>
```

**db_schema.xml**

```
                <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <!--
        /*
         * Copyright © 2019 Krish Technolabs. All rights reserved.
         * See COPYING.txt for license details
         */
        -->
        <schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
            <table comment="Test Table 1" engine="innodb" name="ktpl_test1" resource="default">
                <column identity="true" name="test1_id" nullable="false" padding="10" unsigned="true" xsi:type="int"/>
                <column  name="test_name" nullable="false" padding="10" unsigned="true" xsi:type="int"/>
                <column   name="test2_id" nullable="false" padding="10" unsigned="true" xsi:type="int"/>
                <constraint referenceId="PRIMARY" xsi:type="primary">
                    <column name="test1_id"/>
                </constraint>
               <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="Test12ID" table="ktpl_test1" column="test2_id" referenceTable ="ktpl_test2" referenceColumn="test2_id"/>
               <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="Test13ID" table="ktpl_test1" column="test3_id" referenceTable ="ktpl_test3" referenceColumn="test3_id"/>
            </table>
             <table name="eav_attribute" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Eav Attribute">
                <column xsi:type="mediumtext" name="note" nullable="false" length="500" comment="Note"/>
                <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
                    <column name="attribute_id"/>
                </constraint>
            </table>
        </schema>
```

Answer (score 2):

The only mistake you are doing here is **length** attribute, just remove it.

This is the working code..

**etc\db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="eav_attribute" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Eav Attribute">
        <column xsi:type="mediumtext" name="note" nullable="true" comment="Note"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Comment: getting Invalid Document 
Element 'column', attribute 'length': The attribute 'length' is not allowed.
Line: 297
 error

Answer (score 0):

Create **db_schema.xml** file in your module and add this below code :

> app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/db_schema.xml

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="eav_attribute">
        <column xsi:type="mediumtext" name="note" nullable="true" length="255" comment="Note"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="attribute_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Now, execute this below command in your Magento root directory

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=VendorName_ModuleName
```

Make sure, there are `db_whitelist_schema.json` file will be create in `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc` folder.

Now, upgrade, deploy and clean cache

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
```

[image]

**Hope, it will helpful for you.**

---

### UPDATE :

de_whitelist_schema.json (After install ktpl_test1 table) :

```
{
    "ktpl_test1": {
        "column": {
            "test1_id": true,
            "test_name": true,
            "test2_id": true
        },
        "constraint": {
            "PRIMARY": true
        }
    },
    "eav_attribute": {
        "column": {
            "note": true
        },
        "constraint": {
            "PRIMARY": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error when updating doing s:up
The XML in file "/var/www/html/Magento231new/app/code/Ktpl/Test1/etc/db_schema.xml" is invalid:
Element 'column', attribute 'length': The attribute 'length' is not allowed.
Line: 20

Comment: Did you generate whitelist file?

Comment: yes , i have followed above command

Comment: It seems like there are syntax error of tags. Not sure. Can you please upload your db_schema.xml code?

Comment: already added, i have run above command but db_whitelist_schema.json not generated

Comment: Hey @rohan please check if you can help me

Comment: Error generate from foreign key setup. Make sure that your referenceTable exist in your DB. For check, Just comment foreign key setup 2 line code and clean cache. Then, execute whitelist file create command.

Comment: checked still same error

Comment: Can you please share db_whitelist_schema.json?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96544/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-rutvee-sojitra).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible in magento 2 right now. There is also an issue related to chaning the column type: [Table quote column customer_note uses wrong type](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26155)

This is my fix for that issue:

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Declaration\ReaderComposite;

class ReaderCompositePlugin
{
    public function afterRead(ReaderComposite $subject, $result)
    {
        if (isset($result['table']['quote']) && isset($result['table']['quote']['column']['customer_note'])) {
            $result['table']['quote']['column']['customer_note']['type'] = 'text';
            unset($result['table']['quote']['column']['customer_note']['length']);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```